# How do I test if any of my json's properties has a particular subproperty, without a loop?

Tags: javascript, json, loops

Consider an example:

```
food : {
    cheese: { taste: "delicious", smell: "smelly" },
    bacon:  { taste: "godly", smell: "godly" }
}
```

I would like a loop-less test to see if any of "food"'s properties (cheese and/or bacon ) have  a "taste" that is "godly".

In this case, it would be yes. Testing for "disgusting" should result in false as there is none to have taste : "disgusting"

My question really revolves around a loopless solution, as a hundred property json within several layers of loops is bad :(

Comment: If you know in advance that you're only dealing with cheese and bacon then you can examine the properties directly. I can't see much use for that though. If you have an unknown number of arbitrary foods to handle you have no choice but to look at each one - that's what loops are for. If this is causing a performance problem then maybe a redesign is required, or perhaps extracting and caching certain prpoerties for faster access.

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON would require double quotes around `food`, `cheese`, `bacon`, `taste`, and `smell`. It would also require a top-level object or array. It's the inside of a valid JavaScript object initializer (though not valid on its own), but not valid JSON.

Comment: If you get this object literal populated from a JSON, then you would need to look at the where you get the JSON from (is it from backend service)? And if so, modify the backend service to send the data in a way that is easier to consume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like a loop-less test to see if any of "food"'s properties (cheese and/or bacon ) have a "taste" that is "godly".

You can't. Assuming you've deserialized the JSON into an object graph, you have to have a loop, because you have to test the objects individually.

If you *haven't* deserialized the JSON into an object graph (or if you want to feed that graph back into `JSON.stringify`, though I'm not recommending it — as that would involve a loop), if you still have text, then it may be possible with a regular expression, e.g.:

```
if (jsontext.match(/\b"taste"\s*:\s*"godly"/) {
    // ...something has a taste that is "godly"
}
```

Note that in the above, I've assumed valid JSON. Your question doesn't have valid JSON, because `taste` isn't in double quotes, which is required in JSON.

> My question really revolves around a loopless solution, as a hundred property json within several layers of loops is bad :(

Well, then you need to get whoever is responsible for the JSON to redesign it.

Comment: would have accepted Quentin's answer but the json might change in the loop. it doesn't now, but it might later on. Yeah I have the string json and then the parsed one. I made an unrelated example in the question because my real json involves car related stuff and thought it might hinder getting the solution. thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

You could pre-index all the data by looping over them *once*:

```
var tastes = {}, smells = {};
for (var prop in food) {
    if (food.hasOwnProperty(prop) {
        var item = food[prop];
        if (!tastes[item.taste]) { tastes[item.taste] = [] };
        tastes[item.taste].push(prop);
        if (!smells[item.smell]) { smells[item.smell] = [] };
        tastes[item.smell].push(prop);
    }
}
```

And then, in future, you can just:

```
if (tests.godly) { ... }
```

… which will save you having to loop over the data *every* time you want to query it, but you can't eliminate the loop entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Loops are necessary, in this case.

```
function checkTaste(obj, keyToCheck, valToCheck) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (key === keyToCheck && obj[key] === valToCheck) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

checkKey(food, 'taste', 'godly');
```